# Using 32 bit OS for Java development

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit

My notebook has 4GB of RAM and has a 32-bit version of Ubuntu installed on it. I want to develop Java applications on that notebook.

Will the fact that I use a 32-bit OS for development affect the compatibility of the software I develop/compile/build in any way? More specifically, can I, for example, commit code or build artifacts using maven and no other developer in my team could tell that my OS is 32-bit?

Comment: Java is theoretically platform-independent

Comment: [Write once, run anywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere). The only difference I can think of that you will have that is different from someone with a 64-bit system is that you will be using a 32-bit JDK rather than a 64-bit one.

Answer (score 5):

> Will the fact that I use a 32-bit OS for development affect the compatibility of the software I develop/compile/build in any way? More specifically, can I, for example, commit code or build artifacts using maven and no other developer in my team could tell that my OS is 32-bit?

As long as you're using Java only (and not native code through JNI or JNA), then it will not affect compatibility and no other developers on the team can tell that your OS is 32-bit. In fact, Java works across platforms, architecture and endianness.

Answer (score 2):

Java won't likely be the issue: as Elliott said, it's designed to be used across platforms. The problem will likely be the libraries your team uses *alongside* Java. Specifically, if your team or project needs an external tool or library built for a 64 bit architecture, you won't be able to use it. The opposite won't be a problem: as far as I know, all 32 bit libraries can run in a 64 bit environment (which means you can specify a 32 bit library without blocking your team). I find this to be a problem when working on Android or server projects where some development / production machines are 32 bit and others are 64. This all said, if you are purely using Java, then this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: 32-bit shared libraries cannot be used in a 64-bit JVM (or any other 64-bit application)

Comment: Ah, I'm talking about non-Java libraries, e.g., a build tool required for some other aspect of the project. If you can't use 32 bit libraries in a 64 bit JVM, however, then you should let OP know: he'll need to take that into consideration when using his 32 bit laptop.